# Maximum Resonant Impedance of a piezo disc

Tags: piezoelectricity

I have a couple questions regarding piezo discs.  I have done research on resonant impedance and somewhat understand it.  What I am still confused on is whether or not the MAX resonant impedance would affect output frequency or volume? Below is a graph that I see a lot.  To note, I am not dealing with oscillator controlled piezos, but rather two terminal discs instead.

[image]

If I have two piezos with identical specs other than the *max resonant impedance* and a slight difference (20.2 mm vs 19.7 mm for a 0.5 mm difference between them) in *diameter of the electrode*, and if they are driven by exactly identical circuits, how is the output sound affected?

I have come across another term "average resonant impedance" which I am much less familiar with.  any info on this term is also helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Piezoelectric transducers have several major issues from the driving circuits point of view:

1. Capacitance. Piezoelectric transducers have large capacitive values compared to other transducers. Those for audio and low frequency ultra-sound have a capacitance of about 150nF. These disc are about 1"/25mm in diameter.
2. Those for 1MHZ to 10MHZ ultra-sound are small rectangles epoxied to a resonant plate.
3. Often the driver is custom made for a certain type of Piezoelectric crystal. This protects both the driver and the crystal from non-resonate frequencies and DC offset currents that can warp the crystal.
4. The resonant frequency consumes the least amount of current and produces the highest output level possible. Damage would occur if the intensity of the signal was too strong, and/or the crystal gets too hot due to a lack of a heat sink or high ambient temperatures.
5. The anti-resonant frequency consumes the most amount of current and produces the lowest output level possible. Damage would occur if the intensity of the signal was too strong, and/or the crystal gets too hot due to a lack of a heat sink or high ambient temperatures.
6. It is a basic law of physics that the larger the crystal, the lower the resonate frequency. For a given resonate frequency a small variation in frequency is allowed, with less output as you move further away from the center point of peak resonate output. Most crystals will allow +/-20% at most.
7. I could not find the term "average resonant impedance", at least during the searches I did. However the term "Fundamental Radial Resonance" refers to the center point between the peak resonant frequency and the peak anti-resonant frequency. This is equivalent to the "average resonant impedance". They are not including lower sub-harmonics which emit out the side of the crystal, and the driver amplifier is designed not to allow these out-of-band frequencies.
8. If you can find the source of certain 'terms' used to describe piezoelectric crystal behaviour then we can try to interpret them for you.

The following article covers some basics of impedance vs. resonate frequency.

> The electrical impedance is a distinguishing characteristic for
>   piezoelectric elements. It differs substantially from the impedance of
>   non-piezoelectric dielectric elements when driven at high-enough
>   frequencies. The difference stems from the coupling of electrical
>   energy input to mechanical motion output. Recall that the electrical
>   impedance is defined as the voltage drop across an element divided by
>   the current through the element. For a (simple geometry) piezoelectric
>   element, the electrical impedance over a given frequency range will
>   appear similar to that
>   [shown here](http://www.efunda.com/materials/piezo/electronics/elec_impedance.cfm):

**Impedance Plot**:

> The impedance for a non-piezoelectric element (of the same shape and
>   dielectrical properties) is also shown in blue. The presence of
>   electrical resonances and anti-resonances make the piezoelectric
>   impedance unique. The resonances result from the electrical input
>   signal exciting a mechanical resonance in the piezo element. For each
>   mechanical resonance in the piezo element, a resonance/anti-resonance
>   pair will exist in the impedance.

The following link and PDF goes into much more detail, including materials and shapes vs. resonate properties, thermal limits,
 etc: http://www.piezotechnologies.com/knowledge-desk/overview-piezo-materials

Comment: Great info there!  I am still curious about the "average resonant impedance" I read about.  Is this value dependent on the driving frequency/amplitude?  I hope I'm not getting repetitive.  I just feel like I am completely missing or over-thinking some aspect.  I am dealing with piezo discs that operate as alarm buzzers.  Thus, dealing with the audible range.  Hopefully that helps, as well.

Comment: @AudioGuy. That must be a rare term that you found, or I would have seen it many times by now, as I work with ultra-sound for animal repellers. That is why I suggest in paragraph 7 that the terms "average resonant impedance" and "Fundamental Radial Resonance" are synonymous with each other, in that this is the area of normal operation. The numbers will have to come from a datasheet for a given crystal, as all articles I found stayed with charts and graphs to show relationships, not capacitive or frequency values. In working with them I was far more concerned about their high capacitance value.

Comment: Oh, I did not see paragraphs 7 or 8 at the time.  I don't actually have a scholarly source of those terms being used.  The term has been being used by the person who first brought this question to me. Currently, I have part no. KBS-27DA-5C-105 and the part in question, 7BB-27-4L0, can be found on page 20 of the data sheet here (I hope links are allowed here) http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/sound/p37e.ashx           Basically,  I was told that the average resonant impedance is about the same and then asked how these two differ in theoretical operation.

Comment: If you have another question outside the scope of what I answered, you need to post it as another question.