# What is the relation between resonance frequency and piezoelectric charge coefficient?

Tags: piezoelectricity

We know that the maximum power is lost at the resonant frequency,where the impedance is minimal. On the other hand, when the impedance is minimized, the charge coefficient is maximized. In resonance frequency amplitude of vibration is maximum.how is possible? Is there a relationship between resonant frequency and charge coefficient?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please rotate the image so we do not have to rotate our necks. This question has been asked before and answered.

Comment: Possibly related to: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246637/maximum-resonant-impedance-of-a-piezo-disc?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand their comments because my question is difference.